# Data table evaluating values early

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a loop where I'm trying to programmatically add multiple sets of two columns together.

```
lapply(c("V1", "V2", "V3"),
         function(x){
                   db[, x := get(paste(x, "ACC", sep = "_")) + get(paste(x, "SIC", sep = "_"))] ## e.g. INCIDENT_RATE_STD := INCIDENT_RATE_STD_ACC + INCIDENT_RATE_STD_SIC
         })
```

I would expect `paste(x, "ACC", sep = "_")` to return `"V1_ACC"` howevery looking within the operation of the function, it's evaluating `x` first and telling me that V1 doesn't exist yet. What have I misunderstood about R's ordering?

In the above, `db` is a data.table.

EDIT: I've just discovered that the problem has appeared elsewhere, in code that was working before:

`db[[x]][, LAPSE_DUR := pmin(max(tbls[[x]]$LAPSE_DUR), DURATION_Y)]`

In the above, `db` and `tbls` are lists of data.tables. It is now failing to evaluate `tbls[[x]]` since it's trying to evaluate it within the `db[[x]]` environment rather thana the environment a level up.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Concerning your edit, please can you show the error message? What is `x`? And, what has changed as you are saying *in code that was working before:*? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may better to use `.SDcols` and add with `rowSums` instead of `get` (as it depends on the environment, and another issue is that `+` wouldn't take care of `NA` elements (by default `na.rm = FALSE`)

```
library(data.table)
lapply(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), function(x)
    db[, (x) := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = FALSE), 
        .SDcols = paste(x, c("ACC", "SIC"), sep="_")][])
```

NOTE: We use `:=`, there is no need to assign the output of `lapply` to another object as `db` gets updated with new columns

Comment: Your assumption is correct - modified OP. Want to preserve NAs, but that's a simple modification of what you've provided. Are you aware of why it's evaluating it though?

Comment: @DanielV if there is more than one object. you can use `mget` instead of `get`

Comment: @DanielV it is a bit tricky to work with `get` as you showed in the update because it depends on specifying the correct `envir`